# Java calculator with decimal numbers error?

Tags: java

I was trying to create a calculator with java by using eclipse. I create this code here:

```
package ozan;

import java.util.Scanner;

class apples {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner ozan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double fnum, snum, answer;
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        fnum = ozan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        snum = ozan.nextDouble();
        answer = fnum + snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Whenever I click run its ok. My program fully works with the nondecimal numbers: "1,122,436"

But when i enter a deciaml number just like "1.1" or "5.5" it stops and give an error.

[IMAGE HERE](http://imageshack.com/a/img850/4390/r070.png)

What can i do to fix it?

Comment: I Just tried the same code with both decimals and non decimals and it executed without any issues..

Answer (score 2):

You need to precise a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to your scanner object where decimals are separated by a dot, otherwise it uses your default locale (and it doesn't seem to separate them by a dot in your case).

```
Scanner ozan = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.UK);
```

Comment: True Story - Since here in Germany, a number like 5,987 would be interpreted as 5.987 in England - and thats quite a difference!

Comment: I couldnt input anything. Error at all.

Comment: What do you mean by _"I couldnt input anything "_? That seems weird.

Comment: I mean the script did not run. It tells me that there is an error about the "Locale" in: `(Locale.UK)`

Comment: @user3241040 Did you import it? `import java.util.Locale;`

Comment: Now it works, thank you. The guy that i watched tutorial from did not use `.useLocale(Locale.UK)` thats why i was a bit confused. :)

Comment: @user3241040 Certainly because it's default locale was already separating decimals with a dot.

Comment: Now the question is: I recieved a sum like `15.399999999999999` how to turn that into `15.4`?

Comment: @user3241040 You can format the result : 
  `System.out.println(String.format("%.1f",doubleValue));`.